# How to set host header on the backend request in traefik

Tags: traefik

I am trying to proxy a simple lambda function on AWS through traefik. But AWS is returning status code 403 with message "Bad Request" when tried with the proxied link. I think this is because of the Host header being passed wrongly as seen on other reverse proxies.

I faced the same with nginx as well but this is fixed by providing the  following conf settings

```
proxy_set_header Host <aws_hostname>;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```